# Running a elif statement in a for loop python

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, if-statement

Creating a list where it checks and assigns numbers by the order its listed. Say if it has COVER in the name then its COVER and nothing else. If GLASS COVER then its a COVER, but if only GLASS then its GLASS and should get the number that goes with it. My issue is that if the list has GLASS COVER my list "List_MainNum" gets two values in it, for both COVER and GLASS when I'd like it to be assigned only COVER then ignored for further loops. I though the elif statement would take care of this but I was wrong

```
values = ['COVER','COVER','COVER','COVER','COVER','GLASS COVER','GLASS COVER','GLASS COVER','GLASS COVER','GLASS COVER'
,'SPRING', 'SPRING','SPRING','SPRING','GLASS COVER','COVER', 'SPRING GLASS' ,'TEST','TEST','TEST']
a = []
b = []
List_Main = []
List_MainNum = []
def sub(x,y):
    a.append(text)
    b.append(y)

Remain_List = []

labels = [['COVER', 'SPRING', 'GLASS',], [46,125, 33]] 


for text in values:
    for i in range(len(labels[1])):
        if i==0 and labels[0][0] in text:           
            List_Main.append(text)
            List_MainNum.append(labels[1][0])

        elif labels[0][i] in text:
            sub(labels[0][i], labels[1][i]) 

def Lizt(f,g):
    List_MainNum.extend(b)
    List_Main.extend(a)

Lizt(a,b)

for xyz in values:
    if xyz not in List_Main:
        Remain_List.append(xyz)

List_Main.extend(Remain_List)

print (List_Main)
print (b)
```

Comment: So... does your code work?  If not, what does it do wrong?  It doesn't look like you're asking for an _algorithm_ here.

Comment: No say I have bc, then my final list has bc twice. Once with b’s number and once with c’s number. I just want b’s number

Comment: This question would be massively improved by using consistent and clear names anywhere in it. Your text intro says there are two lists, but in the actual code I have absolutely no clue which of the half dozen different lists correspond to either of the two. The variable names are not self-explanatory. The code does a lot of appending values from one list to another, but I can't get my head around where to even start. I have no idea what the input or the output are in the code, nor what output you got or expected for the example inputs in the intro.

Comment: oh sorry, i'll edit it now

Comment: I’m sure you can tell I’m not a coder. Was just briefly introduced to python in college. Hope my edit helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of treating the keys one at a time, which necessitates **marking** the values that have already been fixed, try considering the values one at a time and finding which key first matches them.  This latter question can be abstracted as a separate function:

```
import operator,functools

def non_prefix(it,f):
  """
  For how many elements of an iterable does a function yield false?
  """
  ret=0
  for x in it:
    if f(x): break
    ret+=1
  return ret

data=["abc","ab","c","a","ab","bc","e"]
keys=["a","b","c","d"]

print([non_prefix(keys,functools.partial(operator.contains,d)) for d in data])
```

This prints `[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 4]`; the 4 indicates that none of the keys matched, so you should reject the value or use whatever default for it (perhaps by having a `labels` list that is one longer than `keys`).

Comment: seems like it could work, I'm trying to create one list with all the values of data, and a list of their respective numbers where the two lists match up

Comment: also my list of numbers is more complicated like [46, 52, 125, 3] that correspond to [a,b,c,d]

Comment: @ChrisBolig: Whether it’s one character or more doesn’t affect string containment tests.  I deliberately wrote this so as to not depend in detail on how `f` operates.

Comment: I was trying it. I was having a issue returning the right number value. Like cover —> 46

Comment: @ChrisBolig: …Use the index to fetch a value from the parallel array (which I called `labels` in the answer)?

Comment: `ret = ret+1
    ret = labels[1][0]` in side the function, if labels[1][1,2,3,...] I think it would get the right num `print([non_prefix(labels[0],functools.partial(operator.contains,d)) for d in values])`

Comment: values and labels reference the edited question I have. I'm not sure what you mean by label longer than keys

Comment: @ChrisBolig: My recommendation is to not edit the generic function—use its returned index to pick a label like 46.  Since it might return `len(keys)`, you need `labels` to be one longer than that if you use `labels[non_prefix(…)]`.

Comment: I'm so close, my problem now is that I want to create a new list but all the "4's" are blank spaces